# Single player game into Multiplayer game

Tags: multiplayer

I developed a Single player game in Flash (Tic Tac Toe) and in the Multiplayer mode i will be able to do both player playing on the same system with out network.

I would like to extend it and make it enable to play the Multiplayer game for two player playing it online.

How i can be made give me some ideas , How test the Multiplayer game playing along with different computers(I do not have internet connection in home).

How I able to change the single player game into Multiplayer game , any minor changes required or I have to change the code base completely.

In which way i can make it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's always better to think of a multiplayer port when writing your engine/code base. Why? Because the game logic have to be located on server and not on client like for single player games.

The first thing you should do is writing (i mean on paper) the protocol your client-server pattern will follow, it will be a list of all messages client and server can receive and what they will do regarding the message.

When the protocol is write down, export your game logic on the server side and only game logic, a server is a non graphical application and all it has to do is handling all gameplay-related stuffs.

Your client, at the opposite, do not have to care about gameplay, calculations etc... it only has to listen for input event and redirect them to server (protocol) and render the game. Actually, the client is a graphical application.

Comment: I would add, that P2P (peer-to-peer) is also a valid option. Then you won't need a server-client approach.

Answer (score 0):

well, most multiplayer games use an even queue system (client-server) where one player sends the server a message, and the server validates it and then sends the results to all clients which have their own queue. So, if you were to turn tic tac toe into that type, have each move send to a queue in the game that would handle both player and ai/other player

However, you can also use a p2p system where each player just sends a move to the other, while validating. You can have a simple system of who's turn it is to send messages. Tic tac toe shouldn't really require much to make into a multiplayer game

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the demo included in the [player.io](http://playerio.com/download/) page it has a multiplayer tic-tac-toe example